# smooth transition when a css file changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I want to allow my users to decide which color theme they prefer the most therefore written different css files for each theme. However, I found it not working pretty smoothly. When I use JS to switch from one theme to another, the original css missed for some time while loading the new one. How can I transit from one theme to another smoothly? There is some sample code:

```
        if (!(localStorage['color-choice'] === element)){
            localStorage['color-choice'] = element
            if(element === 'black'){
                $('#style-homepage').attr('href', '/static/sources/css/index/dark.css')
            }else if(element === 'pink'){
                $('#style-homepage').attr('href', '/static/sources/css/index/style.css')
            }else if(element === 'white'){
                $('#style-homepage').attr('href', '/static/sources/css/index/white.css')
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please, provide as much code as possible to let us [create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please have a look at this demo website http://106.52.41.119:43210/pastpapers/login/

Comment: However, it seems working fine right now... That's quite strange... Are there any alternatives to this method? I just wanted to let my users decide the theme for themselves.

Comment: I used to implement the dark mode on my website through CSS variables. This way all the CSS code was downloaded once, without having to require different files. However, you use caching, so this could be a viable approach, too.

Comment: Yeah, css variables are probably the way to go, you can not really use transition between style sheets. One ide to keep the separate css files is that you can maybe fade out from the active one and fade in to the new one.

Comment: Thank you so much! @PineCode and Scurgery CSS variables are really helpful as a solution to the problem. I really appreciate it!